# Re-loading Cached Session Storage Results for Component When Returning to Tab in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, session-storage

In my Angular 2 app I am subscribing to an observable in the ngOnInit life cycle of my component in order to print a series of records to a table display. This is working as expected:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filtersService.getRecords(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                    this.records = resRecordsData;
                },
                responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError
        );
}
```

I also have some filters on this component. So once a user opens the component, they can further filter the data. The data filters as expected, and will apply filters even as the user paginates through various pages of results (I am loading 12 results per page). I am filtering via a post request, which I'm passing to the API via "this.body":

```
getRecords(page, pagesize, body) {
    return this.api.obsPost(this.strReq, page, pagesize, body);
}
```

This works while I'm paginating (i.e. the chosen filters continue to filter the data) because the same component is still mounted, I'm just passing in "page":

```
private pageChange(page) {
    this.filtersService.getRecords(page, this.pagesize, this.body)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                    this.records = resRecordsData;
                },
                responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError
        );
}
```

The problem I'm running into is, if the user then opens another component, and then, say 30 seconds later, clicks on the tab pertaining to the first component again (because the tab sits there as a background tab in the view), it will re-mount the component, effectively wiping out any of the filters that were applied (as well as any pagination they may have used).

In other words, if they had applied one filter, and moved to page 5 of results in component 1, when they click on the tab again (after having been on a different component/view), the component will re-mount and therefore load with zero filters applied and it will be back to page 1 of results.

I'd like to find a way to somehow cache the state of the first component so that when they click that tab for component 1 again (because it sits there as a background tab while on a different component), they will get the results as they last saw them (i.e., per my example, with one filter applied and on page 5 of results).

How would I go about doing this? Also, because I wouldn't want this to maintain these filtered results perpetually, I assume it'd make sense to do this in session storage. Is there a fairly straightforward way to do this?